# Choose the option that best corrects the comparison error in the following part of the sentence - (accomplished and intelligent like Merlin)

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english, sentence, verb-agreement

Although Merlin was renowned for his superb wizardry and general sagacity, Mingo, his unheralded apprentice, was every bit accomplished and intelligent like Merlin.

a. accomplished and intelligent as Merlin

b. as accomplished and intelligent like Merlin

c. as accomplished and intelligent as Merlin

d. accomplished and intelligent than Merlin

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

I would choose c. If using the word "as" once, it is most often used a second time to complete the comparison correctly. For example, "My pillow is as soft as a cloud." This is the appropriate way to write a classic simile.

Comment: If one wishes to use the word "like",  the word "every bit" could be omitted. This omission would remove part of the strength of your statement. If one wishes to use the word "than", one should write "more accomplished and intelligent than Merlin" instead of "every bit". This would mean that he was better than Merlin rather than equal to him. As your sentence seems to argue that they were equal, using "as" twice seems best to me.

Comment: The phrase at hand is not quiet a simile but a comparison.